# gifs in slideshow or screensaver

Tags: macos, screensaver, slideshow

Is there any way to show gif (animated) images in a slideshow or a screensaver? The screensaver app does not animate the gifs and the only way to view gifs is through Quick Look.

Answer (score 1):

I made a tiny screensaver that can play GIF's and can run in background. It is free and I upload the source code to Github so that every one can look how it is done and participate in further development.

Here is the Github project page: 
https://github.com/Waitsnake/AnimatedGif

And here a ZIP of the compiled screensaver can be found: 
https://github.com/Waitsnake/AnimatedGif/releases/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Since a animated gif is just a collection of multiple slides (frames) I would take the animated gif file and export it as individual frames in to a folder.

Then in screen saver choose that folder.

Now you can adjust the slideshow (animation) to a time of your liking using following n your Terminal: triple click following and copy/paste

```
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set ':JustASlide:mainDuration' 3" /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Slideshows.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Content/EffectDescriptions.plist
```

---> see the number 3 in that long command!

that is in seconds, and you can use (change) to any number that suits you.